# How to disable default endpoint in AWS appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, gateway

Since appsync supports custom domain can we disable the default endpoints similar to api gateway?

Comment: It seems you ahve the capability - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-custom-domain-names-for-aws-appsync-apis/

Comment: @SándorBakos Yes that I know but I want to disable the default endpoints now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So appsync doesn't support disabling default endpoint. But there's a workaround. We can use WAF to block the default endpoint by specifying the host header to match the custom endpoint.